# Can't start a Program because Qt5Cored.dll is missing

Tags: c++, qt5

I compiled a simple Qt 5 project successful in Qt Creator. When run from within Qt Creator it works.
But when i transferred the executable into another location is produces the following error message on the cmd console;

```
The program can't start because Qt5Cored.dll is missing from your computer.
Try reinstalling the program to fix this program.
```

I tried to find Qt5Cored.dll in the Qt5 directory could not find. But strange thing is the program runs from Qt Creator. Any help please. I'm on windows 7 64 bit using Qt5 with MinGW

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The file `Qt5Cored.dll` will exist on your system, otherwise it would not work from Qt Creator either. I think it's just Windows search that lets you down. Open a cmd prompt and do a `dir c:\Qt5Cored.dll /s`

Another note is that those `*d.dll` are debug DLL's, which means you are distributing a debug version of your application. You might want to build a release version for distribution instead. (In which case you'll need `Qt5Core.dll`)

Comment: I did the release version and now it asks for Qt5Core.dll. When I search in the Qt5 directory its there. Can't this be because I do not do static linking?

Comment: Have you tried searching the file on your entire drive using a command prompt? If you use the open-source version of Qt, static linking is against the license.

Comment: They may be find in `QTDIR\5.1.0\mingw48_32\bin` (QTDIR is the directory you install Qt5) if you install Qt5.1.0. Beside them, you may need some dlls in `QTDIR\5.1.0\mingw48_32\plugins` too.

Comment: @newkedison : yes the Qt5Core.dll is there the directories you mentioned.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit: I am facing the same problem as asked by @Amani. I resolved the errors related to `.dll files missing` by copying the .dll files to the release directory where my .exe file is present. **Now when I run the .exe file I dont see any more errors that .dll is missing, unfortunately am unable to see my application come up. I checked the running processes on my windows 7 machine and I see my application .exe file listed in the processes.** Is there something else that am missing here ? Any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: @user12345 I suggest you start a new question

Comment: @user12345 use the standard Qt Windows deployment tool (`windeployqt`), instead of copying DLLs manually, because it is not guaranteed to work otherwise. `windeployqt` does some additional magic under the hood apart from actually copying the DLLs. See this answer for more details: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33292008/504611

Comment: @VickyChijwani i did follow your advice on using `windeployqt`, but i got an error "procedure entry point could not be located _ZNSt18condition_variable4waitERSt11unique_locklSt5mutexE on qt5cored.dll" already tryied using --debug and --relase flag with no avail, any idea what it might be? 
 already check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52121074/qt5-deployment-procedure-entry-point-could-not-be-located

Comment: @lightshadown Sorry I haven't worked with Qt in over 4 years now... 

Answer (score 11):

On my computer the `Qt5Core.dll` and other .dll files are stored here `C:\Qt\Qt5.9.1\5.9.1\xxx\bin` (where xxx is the compiler version). Your Qt version may differ.

Copy the .dll files you want to the application location (where your .exe file is). These are the minimum .dll files I needed to copy for my basic app to work:

- `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll`
- `libstdc++-6.dll`
- `libwinpthread-1.dll`
- `Qt5Core.dll`
- `Qt5Gui.dll`
- `Qt5Widgets.dll`

Comment: thanks. path of yours saved me  hell lot of a trouble. for me path was  C:\Qt\5.12.6\mingw73_64\bin

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was located in this directory. (Qt Version : 5.11.2)
E:\Qute\5.11.2\mingw53_32\bin

On adding all the .dlls in the same dir. program worked.

Answer (score 2):

For the solution what you need to do is to copy the path of the bin folder in your installed Qt creator. Mine was **D:\QTCreator\5.12.10\mingw73_64\bin** and then paste it in the Environment variable of your computer (which can be found in your *advanced system settings* of your PC)

Comment: Which environment variable my friend?

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Qt Creator you have the missing dlls.  Mine were at C:\Qt\5.15.2\mingw81_64\bin.  I added the path to my environmental variables and my executable now works.  This solution allows you to move your application around without moving dlls.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, instead copying .dll files to .exe folder, is to add the .dll location to the path environment.
I added the .dll path to user environment path in Windows 10 and worked.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly problem is that RStudio does not behave well when quitting. Try restarting Windows to properly close the Qt5 libraries.