# Problems with deploying Qt5 application on windows

Tags: qt, visual-studio-2013, dll, deployment, dependencies

So I have Visual Studio 2013 (community edition) with Qt addin installed, Qt5 libraries (32bit), and I'm trying to create an executable that is independent of all development configurations (it may use static or shared libs, I don't really care at this point).

OS: Windows 7, x64.

For doing this I changed the `Solution Confguration` visual studio option from `Debug` to `Release`, and add all the necessary libs in `Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`. The application now starts only if I run it from visual IDE, If I try to start it from the generated `.exe` I got `The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)` error.

I have searched and found that this error code indicates one of the following problems:

- 32-bit app tries to load a 64-bit DLL (not my case I think, Qt DLLs are 32bit (I have installed using this .exe: `qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013-5.5.0`.), and I use some other .DLLs which are also 32bit).
- There are some missing DLLs. (I did copy all the necessary Qt DLLs in the same folder with the final executable).

For checking what dependencies my app requires, I opened the `.exe` file with **Dependency Walker** application, this is what it shows me:

[image: application dependencies]

*in this list were also `Qt5Multimedia.dll` and `Qt5SerialPort.dll`, I get rid of the errors by copying the `.DLLs` in the same folder with the `.exe`.*

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Self-answering questions are welcome on SO. But please seperate the question and the answer. You can edit the question so it contains only the question-part and post the solution as an answer. Otherwise this will look like an open issue and not like a solved problem.

Comment: @Bowdzone Done. Thanks for noticing me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should never do that operation manually unless the standard procedure completely fails. There is already standard tool for Qt Windows deploymend [`windeployqt`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/windows-deployment.html#windeployqt).

It takes care about Qt DLL dependencies, makes a copy of `platforms\qwindows.dll` and also it makes a copy of libraries that you cannot detect with the *Dependency Walker*, since image plugins and some other are loaded at runtime.

You do not even need to have your Qt `bin` folder in your environment `PATH`. The simplest deployment:

- copy built `exe` binary to a new folder
- open `cmd` console in that folder
- call `windeployqt` using its full path (if it is not in the system `PATH`) and provide your executable, for example:

  > ```
  > c:\Qt\Qt5.5.1-vs2013-x64\5.5\msvc2013_64\bin\windeployqt.exe application.exe
  > ```

As a result you have in that folder all needed Qt DLLs. Of course you can have also issues with MSVC redistributables, but those should be deployed separately and installed once per system.

The tool `windeployqt` has various options. It can also take care about deployment of `qml` related files.

Only some 3rd party libraries should be copied manually if they are used, for example OpenSSL.

Comment: This helped with most of my libs, but are the 3D modules an exception?  For me, `windeployqt` seems to copy the Qt3D DLLs, but my resulting app is missing all the Qt3D QML modules.  Am I suppose to deal with the QML modules separately?

Comment: *You do not even need to have your Qt bin folder in your environment PATH* note for future readers: I'm currently at Qt 5.11.2 and it's bin folder is not in my PATH. However, I do have a miniconda's installation Miniconda/LIbrary/bin in my path and that happens to have Qt dlls from a different version of Qt. Due to a bug in windeployqt it picks those dlls from the PATH even though it knows it has to pick the dlls from 5.11.2; it even prints it's doing that in the verbose output), yet it picks up the wrong dlls..

Answer (score 1):

**Solution:**

As I got deeper, I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17023419/win-7-64-bit-dll-problems/20606198#20606198) answer, after doing what that answer indicates (I actually copied all the `.DLLs` located in `\Qt5.5.0\5.5\msvc2013\bin` to the folder where my `.exe` is located), the error message changed from `The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b)` to `Application failed to start because it could not find or load the QT platform plugin “windows”`.

Searching on web for more about this error, I have found from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268558/application-failed-to-start-because-it-could-not-find-or-load-the-qt-platform-pl/25266269#25266269) answer that you also need the `platforms` folder in the same location with the `.exe` (which was located in `Qt5.5.0\5.5\msvc2013\plugins` path). After copying that folder, the application started without any problems!!!

Now I just need to delete all unnecessary `.DLLs` from my application folder (Dependency Walker does not offer very useful information about this), and all the deployment is done.

I have solved the problem in the same time as describing it, so I guess I will just leave this here, may help others that have the same problem.

Comment: That was the only solution that helped... Thanks :D