# Qt5 deployment "procedure entry point could not be located"

Tags: c++, deployment, qt5

**What I have done:**

I'm on Windows 10 and my application is written in C++ / Qt 5.11.1 / MinGW 5.3.0. I compiled it with the release kit and I've run windeployqt from `C:\Qt\5.11.1\mingw53_32\bin` on it. It was still missing `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` and `libwinpthread-1.dll`, so I copied them from `C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin` to the application directory as well.

**The error:**

Whenever I try to start up my app, I get the errors

> Procedure entry point _ZdlPvj could not be located in Qt5Sql.dll
>
> Procedure entry point _ZNSt18condition_variable4waitERSt11unique_locklSt5mutexE could not be located in Qt5Core.dll

From what I can tell, I've removed all qDebug includes from my files and I'm assuming windeployqt copied over the correct dlls. I've tried Dependency Walker, but could not make much of the results, so I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: This means your installed Qt binaries don't match the version of Qt binaries you compiled against. Perhaps there is some other version of Qt in your path.

Comment: @drescherjm I just checked, there is no Qt in my path at all. Out of interest: would the DLLs in the executable's directory not supersede whatever is in path?

Comment: ***would the DLLs in the executable's directory not supersede whatever is in path?*** Yes, They should.

Comment: Are you sure the Qt built with MinGW. Visual Studio binaries will not work.

Comment: @drescherjm I went ahead and deleted my build folder, disabled all kits other than `Qt 5.11.1 MinGW`, rebuilt and reran windeployqt. For some reason, I only got the second error this time.

Comment: @drescherjm I've found the answer. Thank you for getting me on the right track!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that `windeployqt` was unable to locate `gcc` for some reason. I added it to my path from cmd with `SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin`. After I ran `windeployqt` again, I did not have to copy `libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll` and `libwinpthread-1.dll` over manually and it used the correct Qt5Core.dll, since the application is now working fine.