# Unable to run qt-creator executable outside ide compiled in release mode

Tags: qt, dll, qt-creator, release

After switch to release mode to build a small project I have, when I try run it from inside the qt-creator ide, all goes fine. But when I go to the folder `build-<project_name>-Desktop_Qt_5_14_1_MinGW_64_bit- Release` and try run the executable generated in this directory, I got this error:

[image]

Anyone knows what the problem here? If it was some missing dll, I supose it will specify what dll was missing, right? Or I am mistaken?

**update**

After run `windeployqt`, this command found dependencies for my application, create some folders, but now I am getting tis error when try to run it:

[image]

**update 2**

after run the utilitary  `dependency walker`, i got this errors on it:

[image]

I am using this build kit to build the project in qt-creator:

[image]

Comment: You probably have some dlls available in PATH, that's why it doesn't complain about missing dlls. To deploy your app take a look at windeployqt unitlity, it's bundled with Qt

Comment: Use [windeployqt.exe](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/windows-deployment.html) tool to add necessary dlls to the folder where you run the release executable. See also https://wiki.qt.io/Deploy_an_Application_on_Windows

Comment: Where I can find this windeployqt utilitary? I do not find it on the Qt installation direvtory (for me, `D:\Qt\Qt5.14.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin`)

Comment: found `windeployqt`, run it, but still getting errors when I try run my application (update the question with the new error).

Comment: @KleberMota Looks like the problem is related to the compiler libraries. Read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/52127944/4149835

Comment: I try set the PATH variable as the answer described, but still can't run the application. I didn't have to copy any libgcc or libwinpthread library to the directory (they were copiied automaticly), but it was not the same libraries dited on the question (do not know if this is a problem). the libraries copied for the directory were: `libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll` and `libwinpthread-1.dll`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is all I know about Qt deployment & issues on Windows.

1. Check whether Release configuration of your project **doesn't contain links to any debug versions of libraries**.
2. Build your app in Release mode. Use **Rebuild**, If in doubt. **See compile output** window in the IDE, what paths it actually uses.
3. Use **windeployqt** tool to automatically copy all the necessary Qt dlls to the executable's folder. Be sure you are using **windeployqt.exe from the correct folder**. For example, currently I have one version of Qt framework, but two versions of windeployqt: for **x86** and **x64** compilers. In the case you have more than one version of Qt installed, you may have several versions of the tool.

.

```
 C:\Qt\Qt5.14.1\5.14.1\msvc2017\bin\windeployqt.exe
 C:\Qt\Qt5.14.1\5.14.1\msvc2017_64\bin\windeployqt.exe
```

4. Copy compiler libraries to the release folder. Make sure that you're copying libraries from the exact compiler you used to build.
5. Copy all necessary additional 3-rd party dynamic libraries. Make sure it is not debug versions.
6. If the problem persists, press `Ctrl+C` when the error message is active. It will copy all the text from the message box. Paste main part of the message to Google.
7. If the problem persists, open your .exe file in some dll-dependency viewer. Here is how I can see this in [Lister](https://totalcmd.net/directory/lister.html). Be note that such a tool will show you not only missing dlls, **but also a full path for each dll that your executable actually use.** More power tool is [Dependency Walker](https://www.dependencywalker.com/).

[image]

8. Make sure your application doesn't try to write something to a system protected folder, such as `c:\Program Files\`, without corresponding privileges.
9. If the problem still persists, **simplify your project as much as possible**. Run Release for an empty project. Than add modules, functionality and libraries step-by-step.
10. If everything is okay, test the application on a completely clean virtual machine.

---

**Edit.** I google your error text and what I found:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/52127944/

> The problem was that windeployqt was unable to locate gcc for some
> reason. I added it to my path from cmd with SET
> PATH=%PATH%;C:\Qt\Tools\mingw530_32\bin. After I ran windeployqt
> again, I did not have to copy libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll and
> libwinpthread-1.dll over manually and it used the correct Qt5Core.dll,
> since the application is now working fine.

Comment: ok, I use the utilitary `dependency walker`, and got the errors attached on the update 2 in the question. Somehow, the utilitary says, among other things, I am using modules with different cpu's, but I am building the project with the mingw 64 bits, with the 64 bits version of the Qt. Don't know from where this other cpu's modules are coming from.

Comment: @KleberMota If you're sure you had checked all the compiler paths, try to run Qt built-in examples, then simplify your project (or rollback to some old commit if you are using version control)

Comment: @KleberMota I google your error text and what I found:  
https://android.developreference.com/article/11361766/Qt5+deployment+%E2%80%9Cprocedure+entry+point+could+not+be+located%E2%80%9D

Comment: I finally solve this issue, but can't figure out why I solve. What I did: I try a different windeployqt utilitary, using `D:\Qt\Qt5.14.1\5.14.1\msvc2017_64\bin\windeployqt.exe` instead of `D:\Qt\Qt5.14.1\5.14.1\mingw73_64\bin\windeployqt.exe` (which do not copy libgcc, libstdc++ and libwinpthread, copied manually). Why this did work with the msvc2017 version of windeployqt? I am building with the MinGW-64bits kit installed with Qt-Creator.

Comment: @KleberMota Did you check the compile output text in the Qt Creator? What does it actually print?